# Go concurrency in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, go

I wish to use threads and concurrency features of Go language in my Ruby on Rails project. I have several alternatives, one of them is jRuby. But, I don't like Java (personal preference). I have heard that Go Lang is a perfect replacement for Java. Its even more faster & secure than Java. I saw people comparing its speed to C++ as some of its part is in Assembly itself. People can even write a complete web server like Apache from scratch in Go.

What I am really planning for is: All the low level stuff in Go and rest of it Ruby on Rails. I still want to have the ease of development that RoR has to offer.

Comment: You must write Ruby Interpreter in Go language from scratch. Standard MRI is written on C/C++. jRuby is written on Java. It will take A LOT OF WORK for you to reinvent this in Go.

Comment: @QQQ could I not run both languages simultaneously on my server? And create a sort of bridge to communicate between Go and Ruby?

Comment: Alternatively, you could run a few Ruby subprocesses and communicate with them over inter-process communication (stdin/stdout, unix sockets, etc).

However, it sounds like what you really need is the reverse - a Ruby on Rails app which has the functionality to talk across an IPC channel to a Go process which does all of the low-level stuff. For example, want to call out to a Go function from Ruby? Write the arguments and a unique "call ID" to the channel, and then when the Go function returns, write the return values along with the same call ID so that Ruby knows which function just returned.

Comment: no, you can't really do that. It took many many developer-hours to create JRuby. Nobody has yet created a GoRuby.

Comment: Have you actually tried to build a simple web app in Go? Examples, including step-by-step tutorials are ubiquitous in the internets. I'd get some of them a go (pun intended).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in Go 1.5, there is a build mode called `c-shared`, which allows you to build C shared libraries in Go. These can then be loaded into Ruby using FFI and used in your Rails app. See [this brief introduction to the concept](https://c7.se/go-and-ruby-ffi/).